# How to get all links (<a href>) in URL

Tags: java

I get some URL and i need to search all the links in this URL and just show them, thats all.

I write its in java:

```
        PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter("Web.txt");

        URL oracle = new URL("http://edition.cnn.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {

            writer.println(inputLine);
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
```

Now my question is how can I find only links in this huge file?

I thought about `<a href" ... ... ..>`but its not always right..

Thanks

Comment: Why not? What other links are there?

Comment: This may be helpful. Read about Regular Expressions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSOUP](http://jsoup.org) is the way to go! It's a Java API on which you can parse **HTML** documents (either local or external ones) and navigate on it's **DOM** structure using a jQuery similiar syntax.

Your code to get all the links should look something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://edition.cnn.com").get(); // Parse this URL's HTML
Elements elements = doc.select("a"); // Search for all <a> elements
```

Then, to list every link and save it to your file:

```
for (Element element : elements) {
    writer.println(element.attr("href")); // Get the "href" attribute from the element
}
```

Comment: Can you explain please more about JSOUP? does it extern? I need to install it to eclipse?

Comment: Added a little explanation. Basically, it parses this external URL into a Document object, and let you navigate into it's DOM structure.

Comment: And you just need to add this API to your application classpath, no need to install anything.